# #1066 - Not unique table/alias: ? What can I do?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

hi i have a prpblem in my sql statement :( I get the error:

> #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'VERANSTALTUNG'

here is my code:

```
select VERANSTALTUNG.v_name, V_TYP.typ, RAUM.raumname, GEBEAUTE.gebeaute_name From VERANSTALTUNG
JOIN VERANSTALTUNG on VERANSTALTUNG.v_typ_id=V_TYP.v_typ_id
JOIN VERANSTALTUNG on VERANSTALTUNG.raum_id=RAUM.raum_id
JOIN RAUM on RAUM.gebeaute_id=GEBEAUTE.gebeaute_id
```

Comment: From VERANSTALTUNG a
JOIN VERANSTALTUNG b -- and edit the other bits accordingly

Comment: the whole thing is messed up. You aren't bringing in a table or 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a starting point. V1, V2, V3 are aliases, if you even need them all.

You need to bring in tables before you reference them (not in the first select row, but in the joins after the select row).

In other words, you can reference them in the select column list. But you cannot reference them in joins if they are not brought in.

You can't reference `GEBEAUTE` before you have **brought it in**

there are 2 ways of **bringing it in**

- the `from` XXX clause (that is your first table available brought in)
- the `join` XXX clause (that brings in tables 2 and beyond)

.

```
select VERANSTALTUNG.v_name, V_TYP.typ, RAUM.raumname, GEBEAUTE.gebeaute_name
From VERANSTALTUNG V1
JOIN VERANSTALTUNG V2 on V2. something
JOIN VERANSTALTUNG V3 on V3. something
JOIN RAUM on RAUM.gebeaute_id=GEBEAUTE.gebeaute_id -- error here still, see below
```

note you still haven't **brought in** `V_TYP` or `GEBEAUTE`

it's a mess. Less of a mess, but inching toward happiness.

---

Here is a simple illustration of it

```
line1:   select A.col1,B.col2,C.col3
line2:   from table1 A
line3:   join table2 B on B.blahblah=A.something
line4:   join table3 C on C.typ_id=D.month_id
```

It look good until line4. Because table `D` is not **brought in** yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should use another alias for `VERANSTALTUNG` table in join:

```
    select VERANSTALTUNG.v_name, V_TYP.typ, RAUM.raumname, GEBEAUTE.gebeaute_name 
    From VERANSTALTUNG
    JOIN VERANSTALTUNG as t1 on t1.v_typ_id=V_TYP.v_typ_id
    JOIN VERANSTALTUNG as t2 on t2.raum_id=RAUM.raum_id
    JOIN RAUM on RAUM.gebeaute_id=GEBEAUTE.gebeaute_id
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'V_TYP.typ' in 'field list'

Comment: @Tarasov you have no V_TYP, GEBEAUTE tables, so you need to join them relatively to your needs